# Refer to common structure from other structures

Tags: cobol

I need to define copybook, describing my file format. In my file, there are rows of different format, but the first part of all rows is the same. How can I define the common structure only once and refer to it from other structures?
I need something like this:

```
01 Header.
  02 Id PIC X(2).
  02 Name PIC X(10).
01 LineA.
  02 Header.  "how can I reference the above Header, to not define it in every LineA, Line B?**
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
01 LineA.
  02 Header.
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
  ...
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might be looking for COBOL REDEFINE. This allows the same data structure
to have different internal structures which you may choose among at run-time.

For example:

```
  01 TRANSACTION.
     05 TRANS-SQNBR              PIC 9(5).
     05 TRANS-TIMESTAMP          PIC X(26).
     05 TRANS-TYPE               PIC X(2).
        88 TRANS-PO              VALUE '01'.
        88 TRANS-MO              VALUE '02'.
     05 TRANS-DATA.
        10                       PIC X(220).
     05 PO-TRANS REDEFINES TRANS-DATA.
        10 PURCHASE-ORDER-ID     PIC X(10).
        10 CLIENT-ID             PIC X(7).
        10 SHIP-BY-DATE          PIC X(10).
        10 CLIENT-REF-ID         PIC X(30).
        10 .... more Purchase Order data
     05 MO-TRANS REDEFINES TRANS-DATA.
        10 CLIENT-NAME           PIC X(45).
        10 SHIP-ADDRESS-1        PIC X(40).
        10 SHIP-ADDRESS-2        PIC X(40).
        10 SHIP-CITY             PIC X(30).
        10 SHIP-POST-CODE        PIC X(6).
        10 .... More Mail Order Data
```

The above record layout describes some sort of transaction. The first few fields are common
to all types of transaction (TRANS-SQNBR, TRANS-TIMESTAMP and TRANS-TYPE). The TRANS-TYPE
has an associated 88 level which is used to determine how the rest of the record is to be
interpreted. When TRANS-TYPE has a value of '01' (TRANS-PO is true), the record layout for PO-TRANS
will describe the remainder of the record. When TRANS-TYPE is '02' (TRANS-MO is true) the MO-TRANS record layout
should be used.

The TRANS-DATA, PO-TRANS and MO-TRANS record layouts are mutually exclusive because they
will all occupy the same physical memory. That is, the total record length in the above
example is the sum of the common data item lengths (5 + 26 + 2 = 33) plus the length of
TARNS-DATA (220, the data item subject to subsequent REDEFINES). This gives a total record
length of 33 + 220 = 253.  The lengths of the records REDEFINEing TRANS-DATA cannot
exceed the length of TRANS-DATA (they may be shorter, but not longer).

Notice that TRANS-DATA has an unnamed subordinate 10 level. Sometimes this is named FILLER, but
does not need to be given a name. The purpose of this item is to define the length of the
longest area in the alternate record definitions. Basically it is just a dummy place holder.

PO-TRANS REDEFINES the memory that was allocated to hold TRANS-DATA giving it a completely
different interpretation. Similarly, MO-TRANS REDEFINES TRANS-DATA.

The 88 level names under TRANS-TYPE are not really needed but provide documentation and
a defined set of values for choosing among the alternative record layouts.

To use this record layout you would populate it (probably through a READ statement).
The TRANS-SQNBR, TRANS-TIMESTAMP and TRANS-TYPE will be directly available under those
names. In order to interpret the rest of the record you would need to test TRANS-TYPE and
then use the other data names as appropriate to it. For example:

```
 EVALUATE TRUE
    WHEN TRANS-PO
       MOVE PURCHASE-ORDER-ID TO whatever...
       ...
    WHEN TRANS-MO
       MOVE CLIENT-NAME TO whatever...
    WHEN OTHER
       PERFORM UNKNOWN-RECORD-TYPE-ERROR
 END-EVALUATE
```

When using multiple record layouts as illustrated above it is always a good idea to have
an error catch-all in case of bad input, hence the UNKNOWN-RECORD-TYPE-ERROR shown above.

**Response to comment**

The record structure in your question is a bit problematic because the `02 Header.` does not have a PICTURE clause or subordinate data item 
so is not a valid declaration.
If you had someting like:

```
01 Generic-Header.
  02 Id PIC X(2).
  02 Name PIC X(10).
01 LineA.
  02 Header     PIC X(12).
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
01 LineB.
  02 Header     PIC X(12).
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
```

You could do something like:

```
MOVE Header OF LineA to Generic-Header
```

Now you may reference `Id` and `Name` from the Generic-Header. However you have only one
Generic-Header record and if you need to work with both `LineA` and `LineB` at the same time
the `Generic-Header` can hold one or the other but not both at the same time! As in

```
MOVE Header of LineA to Generic-Header
IF Id = Current-Id  <== This is the Id from LineA
   work with LineA
END-IF

MOVE Header of LineB to Generic-Header
IF Id = Current-Id  <== This is the Id from LineB
   work with LineB
END-IF
```

The above is fine, but what happens if you need to compare the Id from LineA to that of LineB. There is only a
single instance of Generic-Header so this becomes a bit problematic.

I'm not saying this a bad approach, but just be aware of the possible limitations.

**Response to second comment**

Maybe you are looking for `COPY`?

Common code may put into another source file, lets call it GENHDR. The content of GENHDR might look
something like:

```
  02 Id PIC X(2).
  02 Name PIC X(10).
```

Your main program would be in a seperate file, lets call it MYPROG. Part of that file would look
something like:

```
01 LineA.
  COPY GENHDR.
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
01 LineB.
  COPY GENHDR.
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
```

When MYPROG is compiled, copies of GENHDR are inserted where the COPY directive is found. The compile
listing would look something like:

```
01 LineA.
  02 Id PIC X(2).
  02 Name PIC X(10).
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
01 LineB.
  02 Id PIC X(2).
  02 Name PIC X(10).
  02 SomeField1 PIC X.
  02 SomeField2 PIC X.
```

In the remainder of your program you can reference the individual fields as:

Id of LineA, SomField1 of LineA, Id of LineB etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks! I think it will solve my problem. But I also want to know if it's possible to define the structure like I made in example: to reference previously defined structure from other structures.

Comment: so, we there is no way to include structure into another structure?

Comment: Thank you for your time! I don't write COBOL program actually, I just need to define the structure of my file using COBOL copybook and pass it to another program, that will analyze the file. I just wanted to avoid copy-pasting common part. I will wait one day and then accept your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the IN keyword (or its synonym OF) to refer to structure members with identical names in different structures.

```
    05  FORMAT-CODE           PIC X(1).
        88  FORMAT-IS-CUSTOMER    VALUE "C".
        88  FORMAT-IS-EMPLOYEE    VALUE "E".
    05  CUSTOMER-LAYOUT.
        07  FIRST-NAME        PIC X(10).
        07  STREET-ADDRESS    PIC X(30).
        07  CUSTOMER-ID       PIC X(7).
* * * 
    05  EMPLOYEE-LAYOUT       REDEFINES CUSTOMER-LAYOUT.
        07  FIRST-NAME        PIC X(10).
        07  STREET-ADDRESS    PIC X(30).
        07  EMPLOYEE-ID       PIC 9(5).
* * *
IF FORMAT-IS-CUSTOMER
    MOVE INPUT-FIRST-NAME TO FIRST-NAME IN CUSTOMER-LAYOUT
* * *
```

The COBOL term for this is "qualification."

In the above fragment, you could place the FIRST-NAME and STREET-ADDRESS definitions in a copy deck and copy  it twice into your program.

You can also use the REPLACING phrase of the COPY statement to generate unique names for the members.  (But I haven't seen this language feature used very often.)

If your interest in this topic is just curiosity, then either way will work for you.  If, however, you are writing production code, your manager and coding standards will dictate how to approach this issue and establish naming standards.  Keep in mind that many COBOL shops depend on a data dictionary facility or integration with a DBMS to generate source code record layouts, so you won't have to code your own DATA DIVISION at all.

Prompted by your follow-up, I remember that the following approach is more like the way I used to do it.  Take advantage of REDEFINES and FILLER:

```
01  ALL-LAYOUTS.
    03  COMMON-LAYOUT.
        05  HEADER.
            07  ID                   PIC X(02).
            07  NAME                 PIC X(10).
            07  FORMAT-CODE          PIC X(1).
                88  FORMAT-IS-A          VALUE "A".
                88  FORMAT-IS-B          VALUE "B".
        05      FILLER               PIC X(67).
    03  LINE-A-LAYOUT                REDEFINES COMMON-LAYOUT.
        05      FILLER               PIC X(13).
        05  LINE-A-SOME-FIELD-1      PIC X(01).
        05  LINE-A-SOME-FIELD-2      PIC X(01).
        05      FILLER               PIC X(66).
    03  LINE-B-LAYOUT                REDEFINES COMMON-LAYOUT.
        05      FILLER               PIC X(13).
        05  LINE-B-SOMETHING-ELSE    PIC X(40).
        05      FILLER               PIC X(27).

* * *

    MOVE "A" TO FORMAT-CODE
    MOVE INPUT-ID TO ID
    MOVE INPUT-NAME TO NAME
    MOVE INPUT-SOME-FIELD-1 TO LINE-A-SOME-FIELD-1
    MOVE INPUT-SOME-FIELD-2 TO LINE-A-SOME-FIELD-2
```

You will want some sort of a record type indicator (FORMAT-CODE) so that when you read the record back from storage you will know which format is applicable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. I updated the question to make it clearer. Could you look?